# Where do you put fields in a class?

Tags: java

At the front of the class or at the end? In the first book I read, they were all at the end of a class like this

```
class AClass {

  public void method() {}

  public int field1;
  public boolean field2;

}
```

So, what is the conventional way, or if there is any convention on this topic?

Comment: doesn't really matter.

Comment: It's primarily opinion-based, my personal preference is at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that fields should be located at the beginning of the class: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#381

Comment: Then I'll do it this way, which is what I originally preffered too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

fields are often put in the beginning of the code or as close as possible to where it's used. There is no limitation in java to where you put them.

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, I see them at the top of the class.

```
public class MyClass {

    private int count;
    private String name;

    public MyClass() {
        // Methods go below.
    }
}
```

I've always done this naturally,  but I think it's better that you put them *all in the same place*. If you've got them dotted around, it just becomes confusing. For example:

```
public void doSomething() {
     x = x * 6; 
}

public void anotherMethod() { 
     y = y * 4; 
}

int x = 0;

public void anotherMethodEntirely() {
     z = z * 10;
}

double y = 0;
float z = 9;
```

You see how it's just counter productive? You want to be able to read the method, and know everything about the nature of the variables involved. Not have to keep firing around the code hunting down members.

If they're all in the same place, however:

```
public void doSomething() {
 x = x * 6; 
}

public void anotherMethod() { 
 y = y * 4; 
}



public void anotherMethodEntirely() {
 z = z * 10;
}

int x = 0;  
double y = 0;
float z = 9;
```

All you need to do is go to the bottom (in this instance) to see the variable types.

**Taken from the Java Code Convention**

> Put declarations only at the beginning of blocks. (A block is any code surrounded by curly braces "{" and "}".) Don't wait to declare variables until their first use; it can confuse the unwary programmer and hamper code portability within the scope.

Full article [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#381)

Comment: You're not quoting the link <strike>I</strike> you gave ;)

Comment: Yeah, of course I won't span them everywhere. I am a law-abiding programmer ^^

Comment: Might be worth marking an answer as correct, to close the question off @bijiDango

Comment: oh, sure, I'll figure it out